# How to delete a folder and its contents on Amazon S3 using Python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

For some reason my response only gives me empty square brackets, i.e [ ] and nothing happens.

Here's my code:

```
session = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id=awsaccesskey,aws_secret_access_key=awssecretkey,region_name='eu-west-1')
s3 = session.resource('s3')
b = s3.Bucket(s3bucket)
r = b.objects.filter(Prefix=s3path).delete()
return(r)
```

Update: Per John's recommendation I tried to create a test bucket but unfortunately I received a permissions denied error. So instead I did the following:

- Created a folder, under the bucket which I have access to, named 'test'
- executed above code with Prefix='/test/'

This time I did receive a ResponseMetadata object instead of empty brackets. However I'm still puzzled. My HTTPStatusCode is 200. But when it tells me what it deleted it says this:

- 'Deleted': [{'Key': '/test/table_name.dat'}, {'Key': '/test/table_name.txt'}]}]

  I guess I don't understand the intended functionality of this code. I was expecting it to delete my empty 'test' folder which I created as a root folder inside my bucket. i.e. bucket/test/  but instead it appears to have searched my entire bucket for folders named "test" and deleted objects inside them??

Comment: **Side-note:** It is recommended that you do _not_ include Access Key / Secret Key within your code. Instead, store credentials in a credentials file by running `aws configure`.

Comment: Your code worked fine for me, with my own bucket and path. You might want to create a test bucket, upload some objects and try it again. If that fails, please edit your question to describe the _exact_ steps you took so that we can try to reproduce your situation.

Comment: Thanks @JohnRotenstein for testing my code and confirming it worked for you. I will try your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

First of all following are some pointers: Never hardcode access credentials in boto3 client object.

There are no folders in S3. Instead, the keys form a flat namespace. However a key with slashes in its name shows specially in some programs, including the AWS console (see for example Amazon S3 boto - how to create a folder?).

Instead of deleting "a directory", you can (and have to) list files by prefix and delete. In essence:

for key in bucket.list(prefix='your/directory/'):
    key.delete()

You may refer this link and one example is bundled here :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/python-s3-delete_object.py.html

```
import logging
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

def delete_object(bucket_name, object_name):
"""Delete an object from an S3 bucket

:param bucket_name: string
:param object_name: string
:return: True if the referenced object was deleted, otherwise False
"""

# Delete the object
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
try:
    s3.delete_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=object_name)
except ClientError as e:
    logging.error(e)
    return False
return True
```

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for this answer today and I was very frustrated that this was my top hit, but it didn't actually have a good solution. I realise this is 3 years too late to help the OP. Here's a brief summary of what is required, and then some surprisingly long python code to delete everything below a certain prefix. Note that if you want to empty an *entire* bucket, this code will work (set `prefix='/'`) but there are more efficient ways. Note also that if your bucket has versioning turned on (which annoying security standards insist on, regardless of whether it makes sense), this does not delete every version. So there could still be object versions left after this script runs.

Importantly, if you have more than 1000 objects in your bucket, you have to handle 'pagination', which is explained [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/paginators.html). The idea is that you can fetch a large number of keys in one API call (up to 1000, but you can do smaller pages if you want), and then you have to iteratively go back and fetch more and more pages. You can delete a lot of keys in one API call, too (again, up to 1000). This code handles iterating through all the objects under a certain prefix, one "page" (group of keys) at a time. It also has some fairly basic error handling, which adds a few more lines.

To use this code, simply save it as a file, change the `prefix`, `bucketname`, and `pageSize` variables, and you're off to the races.

```py
import botocore
import boto3

# prefix must NOT start with a /, but MUST end with a slash:
# "prefix/" = OK. "/prefix/" = BAD. "/prefix" = BAD. "prefix" = BAD.
prefix     = "myprefixname/"
bucketname = "mybucketname"
pageSize   = 200 # Will handle this many objects per API call. 1000 is AWS max.

def emptyFolder( bucketname: str, prefix: str):
    """Given a bucket name and prefix, delete all objects in that bucket with
       that prefix. E.g., emptyFolder( "mybucket", "temp" ) will delete all
       objects in s3://mybucket/temp/.
       
        :param bucketname: Name of the bucket
        :param prefix: Prefix of objects to delete. Specify None to delete all objects
        :return: Nothing. Deletes objects.
    """
    page = 0
    iterator = None
    try:
        session = boto3.Session( )
        s3 = session.client('s3')
        paginator = s3.get_paginator( 'list_objects_v2' )
        iterator = paginator.paginate( Bucket=bucketname, Prefix=prefix, 
            PaginationConfig={ 'PageSize': pageSize })
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError  as e:
        raise Exception("boto3 client error in paginate: " + e.__str__())
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception("Unexpected error in paginate: " + e.__str__())

    for s3Page in iterator:
        page += 1
        objectList = [{'Key': obj.get('Key')} for obj in s3Page.get('Contents', []) ]
        print( f"Deleting {len(objectList)} objects, page {page}")
        if objectList:
            try:
                response = s3.delete_objects( Bucket=bucketname,
                    Delete={ 'Objects': objectList } )
            except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
                raise Exception("boto3 client error in delete_objects: " + e.__str__())
            except Exception as e:
                raise Exception("Unexpected error in delete_objects: " + e.__str__())
            if( response.get('ResponseMetadata')['HTTPStatusCode'] != 200 ):
                raise Exception("Unexpected HTTP response: " + 
                    response.get('ResponseMetadata')['HTTPStatusCode'] )
if __name__ == "__main__":
    emptyFolder(bucketname=bucketname, prefix=prefix)
```

I do something in 2 steps (lines 24 and 25 where I get `boto.Session()` and then `session.client()` which could actually be done in 1 step. The reason is that I use profiles for my own `~/.aws/config` file. So for me, I have to modify line 24 to say `boto.session( profile_name='myprofile' )` in order to invoke the right set of credentials in my `~/.aws/config`. If you're pulling all your session info from your AWS environment (e.g., `AWS_REGION` `AWS_PROFILE` and so on) you don't have to do that.

#### Warnings

This is pretty crude. It will get the job done, but there are lots of reasons why it can blow up while running. It pretty much quits if there's any error. Sometimes you have credentials that are short-lived. (e.g. a role that only allows credentials issued for 15 minutes at a time) So if you have gajillions of objects to delete, it's possible for your credentials to expire before the script finishes its work, and it just blows up in the middle with boto ClientError exceptions. It's safe to just restart. Or you could take this, build on it, and add in new mechanisms to get a new Session() with new temporary credentials.

Answer (score 0):

```
client = boto3.client('s3')
response = client.list_objects(
    Bucket='bucket_name',
    Prefix='folder_name/'
)
obj_list = []
for data in response.get('Contents', []):
    print('res', data.get('Key'))
    obj_list.append({'Key': data.get('Key')})
if obj_list:
    response = client.delete_objects(
        Bucket='buket_name',
        Delete={'Objects': obj_list}
    )
    print('response', response)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Answer (score -2):

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
my_bucket = s3.Bucket('mybucket')

for obj in my_bucket.objects.all():
    print(obj)
```

Comment: This code will not work. The `s3.Bucket()` command expects the name of a bucket, not a path.